# Remove dynamic script tag on src match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have a web page which is working fine on my local machine, but when it is moved to the server, an ad script from google overwrites page image src.
I want to find that particular script tag with that src and remove it.  I know the url, but can not add an id or modify the DOM. Please help.

for eg:

```
<script src="one.js"><script>
<script src="two.js"><script>
<script src="three.js"><script>
```

so if

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName ( "script" );
var l = scripts.length;
for ( var i = 0; i < l; ++ i ) {
    if ( scripts[i].src ="one.js") {
        //remove that particular script tag with one.js
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do it by : scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i])

Comment: This may not do you any good - removing the script tag will have no effect once the script within has already loaded and run.

Comment: Instead of looping, you can use `document.querySelector("script[src='one.js']")` @PaulRoub, Your point is valid!

Comment: You could maybe catch it before it has loaded with [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) but the best is probably to get what the script does, and undo it after him.

Comment: hmm is there any alternative by which we can stop loading that particular script ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paul stated in the comments, removing an already loaded script wont do any change. But, for the sake of it:

```
$('script[src*="one.js"]').remove();
```

with jQuery (as this question is tagged).

Edit: for more info about attribute selectors (like `*="string"`) have [read here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Comment: What is the use of `*` in selector ? pls explain!

Comment: @RayonDabre it means select any `<script>` tag which's `src` attribute somewhere has the string `one.js` in it, while the position doesnt matter. `^=` means has to start with, `$=` means has to end with

Comment: I would suggest you to provide this info in your answer as it sounds very helpful!

Comment: @RayonDabre it is common knowledge, have a read here: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: @Kaiido you cant compare selectors with methods :)

Comment: @Kaiido those selectors are not jQuery specific, while `remove()` on a jQuery object is...

Comment: To complete what @Alex mentioned about the [selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for the sake of knowledge 
`!=` means not having the attribute or value,  `~=` means containing a given word, delimited by spaces

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer per say, but still i have a gut feeling that i should post this workaround.

So if I were you,  maybe I'd try to trap the script by creating the fake set of elements that the script is meddling with and then verify if the respective data has changed ad then delete that div.

Better explained step by step.

1. Introduce a fake div with similar Dom before our concerned div. Now if there are two divs with same Id then that script shall target the first div with that id.
2. You check if the content of our Trojan div is changed, if yes then remove it from the Dom.
3. Now execute your script.
4. Also as a counter measure just remove all the events that are delegated to that div. If the rogue script is jquery based, even better, since you can remove the respective event and bind your own, using the `.off()` function. As shown below..

   `$("#xyz").off().on('click', function(){});`

Comment: I am on my mobile at the moment, so if any formatting is wrong/missing plz ignore it, or even better fix it. ;)